# Required a sample png to bitmap image to memory - stbi

Tags: c, png

I am writing a sample code for converting png image to bitmap. This is a part of big project, trying a sample first.

Everything is working fine using below code. Only problem is I need to save the converted data into memory and not supposed to write to the disk. But I don't find any function call to convert into bitmap and give me converted data. I have only write to disk method.

Here is the working sample to stbi_load_from_memory and write converted image to disk

```
int main() {
    // Specify the file path
    const char* file_path = "img1.png";
    long file_size;
    int width, height, channels,result;
    unsigned char *file_data, *image_data;
    unsigned int bytes_read;

    // Open the file in binary mode
    FILE* file = fopen(file_path, "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", file_path);
        return 1;
    }

    // Determine the size of the file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Allocate memory for the file content
    file_data = (unsigned char*)malloc(file_size);
    if (file_data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    // Read the file content into memory
    bytes_read = fread(file_data, 1, file_size, file);
    fclose(file);

    if (bytes_read != file_size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file: %s\n", file_path);
        free(file_data);
        return 1;
    }

    // Load image data from memory
    
    image_data = stbi_load_from_memory(file_data, file_size, &width, &height, &channels, 0);

    if (image_data != NULL) {
        // Image loading was successful

        // You can now use the 'image_data', 'width', 'height', and 'channels' variables as needed.

        // For example, print some information about the image:
        printf("Image Width: %d\n", width);
        printf("Image Height: %d\n", height);
        printf("Number of Channels: %d\n", channels);

        // Save the image as a BMP file
        result = stbi_write_bmp("sampleres.bmp", width, height, channels, image_data);

        if (result != 0) {
            printf("BMP file saved successfully: %s\n", "sampleres.bmp");
        } else {
            printf("Error saving BMP file: %s\n", "sampleres.bmp");
        }

        // Clean up the allocated image data when done
        stbi_image_free(image_data);
    } else {
        // Image loading failed
        printf("Error loading image from memory.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
I also tried dumping image data on to disk. Didn't work

```
// Write the data to the file
    bytes_written = fwrite(image_data, 1, file_size, file);

    if (bytes_written != file_size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to file:");
    }

    // Close the file
    fclose(file);
    }
```

Anyone has a sample to convert into bitmap and give me converted data in a variable or a memory structure?

Comment: It's open source, you should be able to hack that feature into the library.

Comment: `stbi_load_from_*` converts all images to bitmaps, stores them in the memory, and returns a pointer to the memory location. You have already implemented what you need.

Comment: @TippuR, better to check the return value of `ftell(file);` as pictures can be quite large.

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat I added Edit. Where I wrote the imagedata to disk. Got invalid bmp file

Comment: What conversion exactly are you looking for in "But I don't find any function call to convert into bitmap and give me converted data."? The data at `image_data` _is_ a bitmap.

Comment: And you certainly can't expect that writing a raw bitmap to a file would result in a valid BMP file. A BMP is an image file format with the bitmap and _information about the image_. (See the wikipedia entry.)

Comment: Bitmap is not bmp. Bmp is a file format and therefore has to have metadata appended to it. Do you want bmp or bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes at `image_data` *is* the bitmap. There are `height` * `width` * `channels` bytes there, in that order from highest dimension to lowest. So it starts with `channels` bytes, repeated `width` times for each row, with `height` rows. Done.